# Rhostudio cannot run android simulator

Tags: rhomobile

I try to run android simulator in Rhostudio on Windows 7, but below error is showing, what could be the problem? Please help me!

```
process additional java files for build from extensions :
ext_build.files not found - no additional java files
PWD: D:/bin/RhoStudio/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhodes-3.3.2
CMD: "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/javac.exe" -g -d D:/Messenger/bin/tmp/Rhodes -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -nowarn -encoding latin1 -classpath D:/Bin/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/android.jar;D:/Messenger/bin/tmp/Rhodes @C:/Users/Pete/AppData/Local/Temp/RhodesSRC_build20120325-2984-1ejkqvm-0
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/javac.exe" -g -d D:/Messenger/bin/tmp/Rhodes -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -nowarn -encoding latin1 -classpath D:/Bin/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/android.jar;D:/Messenger/bin/tmp/Rhodes @C:/Users/Pete/AppData/Local/Temp/RhodesSRC_build20120325-2984-1ejkqvm-0

Tasks: TOP => run:android => run:android:emulator => device:android:debug => package:android => build:android:all => build:android:rhodes
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Error in build application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I do not set correct path for the Java SDK.